# how to remove zero matrix in numpy for hyperspectral bands?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I'am setting up the environment to extract all the hyperspectral imagery bands (.tif) and plot bands as required. As there are 220 bands i.e 220 images load together with a lot of nulls (zero) matrix, I need to clear the array then need to call 3 bands as required at a time. How to control HSI cube and plot it accordingly?

```
import cv2
import os
import glob
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

img_dir = "DataPrac" # Enter Directory of all images 
data_path = os.path.join(img_dir,'*.tif')
files = glob.glob(data_path)
data = []
for f1 in files:
    img = cv2.imread(f1)
    data.append(img)
    plt.imshow(img)
```